# what does DBCC DBREINDEX('?', ' ', 80) do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What exactly does the following statement do? Does it reindex all tables named '?' with a fill factor of 80% ?

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' DBCC DBREINDEX ('?', ' ', 80)"
```

It did improve query time from 23 seconds to almost instantly but I'd like to understand why.

Comment: al right. and the space for index name means all existing indices?

Comment: Correct. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181671.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not quite - when you use `sp_MSforeachtable`, the question mark is a placeholder for the the table name (as it loops through each table in turn).

In reply to your second question from the comments, yes - according to the documentation on [DBCC DBREINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181671.aspx) about the second argument:

> If index_name is specified, table_name must be specified. If
>   index_name is not specified or is " ", all indexes for the table are
>   rebuilt.

Comment: Table name, not database name. There's also sp_MSforeachdb, which does use `?` for the database name.

Comment: @hvd Sorry, too early for me. You're correct of course, that's the one I was thinking of!

Comment: DBCC DBREINDEX has been [deprecated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx), or marked for removal in a future version of SQL Server.  [This page](http://jamessql.blogspot.com/2012/06/rebuild-index-with-alter-index-rebuild.html) tells how to use ALTER INDEX REBUILD instead.